# Delete Query And Refresh in ListView in Android (sqlite)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to Java, Android, and SQLite, and I'm stuck at this. I have columns, namely `_id` (autoincrement), `type`, `amount` (int), `category`, and `description`. Three queries.

Firstly, I am not able to delete a transaction (row) retrieved from database. (Please refer to the attached Logcat).

Secondly, I need to know how to refresh the ListView after deleting the entry.

And third, the silly issue I think. If I open the database once and retrieve data, it does so. Further, without closing the database, if I delete a transaction it does not delete it and gives the error "database not open". Further, if I close the database after retrieval and then open again at the time of deletion, it works. I dont get it. Main issue is the first one, but please answer if you know any of the above

```
    final ListView lv = getListView();
    localArrayList.clear();                //To Stop the silly repeating issue
    localDbCrud = new DbCrud(this);
    localAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            localArrayList,
            R.layout.transaction_list_item,
            new String[]{"Amount","Category","Date","Description"},
            new int[]{R.id.tli_amount,R.id.tli_category,R.id.tli_date,R.id.tli_desc});

    localDbCrud.open();
    DbCrud.getAllTransaction();             //Using HashMap localHashMap , localHashMap.put(localArrayList) in loop
    localDbCrud.close();
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                 final int arg2, final long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder ladbuilder = new Builder(TransactionList.this);
            ladbuilder.setTitle("Choose Your Option");
            ladbuilder.setItems(R.array.alertdialog_prompt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selected_item) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (selected_item == 0){
                        localDbCrud.open();
                        HashMap itemMap = (HashMap)localAdapter.getItem(arg2);
                        int item_id =(Integer) itemMap.get("Id");
                        DbCrud.deleteTransaction(item_id);
                        //final int ite=  (Integer) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                         // final int item_id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DbCrud.TN_ID));
                        //DbCrud.deleteTransaction(item_id);
                        localDbCrud.close();

                    }
                    else{


                        //update code

                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog localad = ladbuilder.create();
            localad.show();


            return false;
        }
    });

    localDbCrud.close();

    setListAdapter(localAdapter);

}
```

Logcat

```
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at com.hishighness.budgetracker.TransactionList$1$1.onClick(TransactionList.java:62)
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:878)
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3701)
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1970)
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-13 01:21:26.804: E/AndroidRuntime(22023):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here's the getallTransaction() function.This is the only trace of hash map in my project

```
    public static void getAllTransaction(){

    Cursor localCursor = localDatabase.query(true, TN_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null, null) ;
    if (localCursor != null) {

        localCursor.moveToFirst();
            do{
                HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
                temp.put("Amount", localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndex("amount")));
                temp.put("Category", localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndex("category")));
                temp.put("Date", localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
                temp.put("Description", localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndex("description")));
                temp.put("Id", localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                TransactionList.localArrayList.add(temp);



            }while (localCursor.moveToNext());

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firstly, I am not able to delete a transaction (row) retrieved from database

Line 61 is casting the result of `arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)` to `Cursor`, but the return type is probably `HashMap` (as it says in the Logcat output). Normally you get a `Cursor` from a database query.

If you put the ID for each database row into the `HashMap` when you're building it, then you'll be able to pass that ID to your `deleteTransaction()` call in your `onClick` event. So, you need

```
temp.put("Id", localCursor.getInt(localCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
```

in `getAllTransaction()`, and then revise your `onClick()` method to do something like this:

```
localDbCrud.open();
HashMap itemMap = (HashMap)localAdapter.getItem(arg2);
int item_id = Integer.parseInt((String)itemMap.get("Id"));
DbCrud.deleteTransaction(item_id);
localDbCrud.close();
```

I would also suggest renaming `arg2` (and others) to have clearer names so that the code is easier to follow.

> Secondly, I need to know how to refresh the listview after deleting the entry

You can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter to refresh the `ListView` after you've made a change to the dataset.

EDIT: Please note that `SimpleAdapter` is meant for static data, so your mileage may vary. The best solution is probably to switch to a different type of adapter, such as `ArrayAdapter`, or make a new `SimpleAdapter` every time you change the dataset.

Comment: I have used hash map to retrieve data , but how would that matter.Further if type casting is the problem,how do you suggest should I proceed...

Comment: It's difficult to give a clear answer based on the code above, but you probably want to do something like this: `Cursor c = localDbCrud.query(table_name, null, "_id=" + arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2), null, null, null, null);`

Comment: i cannot call the query in the current class.i need to call a function in DbCrud for that.i'm still stuck on this..

Comment: It sounds like you need a way to convert between the integer ID that you get from `getItemAtPosition()` and the corresponding _id value that will match your database row. If you can pull the _id value directly from your `HashMap`, then you don't need a `Cursor`. Just pass the value from the `HashMap` to `deleteTransaction()`. Without seeing more code, I can't suggest anything more precise.

Comment: which part of code do you want.i could upload it because im really stuck and cant find anyway foward

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some details about the data stored in `localHashMap`? Specifically, what are the keys in the `HashMap` and what are their datatypes?

Comment: You're still seeing a ClassCastException? Please update your post with the new changes.

Comment: new line 61 `int item_id =(Integer) localAdapter.getItem(arg2);`

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my updated code. It should be `int item_id =(Integer) localAdapter.getItem(arg2).get("Id");`

Comment: `the method get(string) is undefined for type object` if i add .get

Comment: You need to cast the `Object` to a `HashMap`. `HashMap itemMap = (HashMap)localAdapter.getItem(arg2);` and then `int item_id = (Integer) itemMap.get("Id");`

Comment: log updated.Also i used getstring instead of getint in getalltransactions().Can that be the problem

Comment: Yep. You'll need to use `getInt()` since the primary key is an integer.

Comment: cannot use getint() in hasp map as it is <String,String>

Comment: Ok. Then use your `getString()` method in `getAllTransactions()` and `int item_id = Integer.parseInt((String)itemMap.get("Id"));` in the click handler.

Comment: Its WORKING!!!Thanks..Now the second ques `localAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` not helping

Comment: Excellent. :) I updated my answer to the second question. I hadn't realized that you were using `SimpleAdapter`.

Comment: you see i'm a noob if now i focus on arrayadapter.i will seriously kill my time in this college project.is there any other way round because i will have to do deleteTransaction also again which i dont think would be such a mess.will it be.At last can u direct me to an appropriate example using array adapter.thanks a ton btw

Comment: You're most welcome. There's an `ArrayAdapter` tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) and a bare-bones one [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1516). It shouldn't be too hard to transition from `SimpleAdapter` to `ArrayAdapter` given your current implementation. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks i'll try them in the morning.On a last note can you please Explain in Detail what are we doing when deleting a row according to your code,that would be very Helpful

Comment: You're storing your data in an `ArrayList` that contains `HashMap` objects. When your click handler is executed, it tells you which item in the list was clicked. We use that information to retrieve a specific `HashMap` from the `ArrayList`. Then we pull the `Id` field from the `HashMap`, which corresponds to the `_id` field in the database row for the list item that was clicked. Then we delete the row with that `_id` value.